# Multiple Gmail Accounts

Tags: email, gmail

Am I able to add a second email address to my phone. On the iPad I know you can have an inbox for multiple email addresses. Can I do this so I have my personal emails and a secondary one in the gmail app? They are both gmail accounts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, to get this working just click on the button on left upper side of window and click on you email, now you'll get option to add another account.
[image]

*P.S on the image it shows "Personal" you just click on "Google" since it's Google account

Comment: Ahhh thank you! I was trying to do it from settings...